# Mapping/macro to 'smartly' auto-create pairs of apostrophes in vim (and ignore contractions)

Tags: vim

I'm currently using closepairs for my auto-closing needs, and it works pretty well.  However, there is one caveat -- apostrophes.  Don't get me wrong, I need apostrophes closed all the time.  I don't want to just disable them.  But whenever I type in plain text, whenever there are any contractions (I'm, Don't, Can't)...these apostrophes get made.

Now I could just type  to delete them as soon as they can, but doing it every time is a bit impractical.

Does anyone know how I can possibly modify the closepairs script to only autoclose single quotes/apostrophes if they are the start of a word?  That is, they are preceded by a whitespace character?

Here is the current code:

```
inoremap <expr> " <SID>pairquotes('"')
inoremap <expr> ' <SID>pairquotes("'")
function! s:pairquotes(pair)
    let l:col = col('.')
        let l:line = getline('.')
        let l:chr = l:line[l:col-1]
        if a:pair == l:chr
            return "\<right>"
        else
            return a:pair.a:pair."\<left>"
endf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know *closepairs*, but the [AutoClose - Inserts matching bracket, paren, brace or quote](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) plugin handles this well. You'll find a list of plugin alternatives on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters).

Comment: I think for some reason autoclose caused a major performance hit on my vim that I couldn't figure out, so I couldn't use it.  Even if I now could, I'm interested in learning how to write my own.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to autocomplete only after whitespace? In that case, something like `function('string')` would not autocomplete after the parenthesis.

Regardless, you can check the previous character against some regex. For example, to avoid autocompletion after letters:

```vimscript
function! s:pairquotes(pair)
    let l:line = getline('.')
    let l:col = col('.')
    let l:chr = l:line[l:col - 1]
    let l:prev = l:line[l:col - 2]

    if l:chr == a:pair
        return "\<right>"
    elseif l:prev !~ "[A-Za-z]"
        return a:pair . a:pair . "\<left>"
    else
        return a:pair
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that there are exceptions even with this conservative example, like typing `r'regex'` in Python, so it might also make sense to define filetype-specific behavior.